# Post Request with bad request 400 batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl, post, nginx, bad-request

I am using the command line tool `curl` on my Windows Server 2012 standard. The actual command from my batch file is:

```
start cmd /K "cd C:\Users\Administrator.PD\mycurl && curl -L -H "X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key: xxxx" -X Post -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"\name\":"\test\"}" "https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations""
```

If I start my batch file I get this error massage:

> ```
> <html>
> <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
> <body bgcolor="white">
> <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx</center>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: `start "" cmd /K ^"cd /D "C:\Users\Administrator.PD\mycurl" ^&^& curl -L -H "X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key: xxxx" -X Post -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"\name\":"\test\"}" "https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations"^"`

Comment: i dont know what for what is the /D ?

Comment: `/D` also switches the drive, so when you are currently working on drive `D:` and do `cd "C:\Test"`, you won't see any change, but with `cd /D "C:\Test"` you will. Type `cd /?` into a new command prompt window and read the help; see also [this](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)...

Comment: I get now an other message. After i start the request i get:  "the syntax of the filename, directoryname or  volume label is incorrect. It is not enough storage for this request available".

Comment: Well, I don't. Are you sure you copied it correctly? Note that I added `/D` but this is not the solution to your problem, the actual problem was the nested quotes in your code...

Comment: I have now changed the request. The actuall request is now:

start "" cmd /K ^"cd /D "C:\Users\Administrator.PD\mycurl" && curl -L -H "X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key:xxxx" -X Post -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"\name\":"\vom Server\"}" "https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations"^"

Now i get only one error message: Not enough storage for the request available..

Comment: This appears to be an error message related to `curl` which I am unfortunately not familiar with, sorry...

Comment: thank you for your help :))